# Rewriting nested loops using parallel where the arguments for second loop depends on arguments of first loop

Tags: parallel-processing, gnu-parallel

Use case:
I have two nested for loops in which the arguments provided to the second loop depends on the arguments provided to the first loop.

```
for node in `ls -l $dir | grep $pattern1`
do
   for part in `ls -l $dir/$node | grep $pattern2`
   do something using $node and $part
done 
done
```

To rewrite this using parallel I created a function:

```
doit(){
$node=$1
$part=$2
do something using $node and $part
}

parallel doit ::: <arguments for first for loop> ::: <arguments for second for loop>
```

How do I provide these arguments when running using parallel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GNU Parallel cannot do that directly, so you need to generate the combinations by hand:

```
for node in `ls -l $dir | grep $pattern1`; do
    for part in `ls -l $dir/$node | grep $pattern2`; do
        printf "$node\t$part\n"
    done
done | parallel --dry-run --colsep '\t' doit {1} {2}
```

You may be able to use `skip()` like this:

```
parallel --dry-run doit '{= -e "$arg[1]/$arg[2]" or skip() =}' ::: all nodes ::: all parts
```